# If condition error in r

Tags: r

I have two variable a and b

```
 A      B
 1      id
-1      asddnewid
13      asddsatransID 
-1      sadsddsdasd
-1      asdsadasdd
```

I want to find if a is > 0 then i want to search the variable B for character "transid" and get the index of it.

I tried the below code

```
if (a > 0) {
c = regexpr("transid=",B)
}
```

But it showing error. I am not sure whether iam writing the if condition properly

Comment: What should be the expected output

Comment: the output should be 7 for 3rd row.

Comment: Updated the answer.  Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep`.  If we need the index from only the positive values in "A"

```
 grep("transID", df1$B[df1$A>0])
 #[1] 2
```

If the index is based on all the rows

```
i1 <- which(df1$A >0 & grepl("transID", df1$B))
i1
#[1] 3
sapply(gregexpr("transID", df1$B[i1]), c)
#[1] 7
```

Or just

```
r1 <- sapply(gregexpr("transID", df1$B[df1$A > 0]), c)
r1[r1 >0]
#[1] 7
```

---

Regarding using `if` condition, `if` is not vectorized, so it may be good to use `ifelse`.  However, from the OP's post, the `a` is not defined.  I am assuming that the OP meant `A`.

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, -1L, 13L, -1L, -1L), B = 
c("id", "asddnewid", 
"asddsatransID", "sadsddsdasd", "asdsadasdd")), .Names = c("A", 
"B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: I applied the same concept for a datatset.                                                                la1$r1 <-sapply(gregexpr("transid=",la1$dvr[la1$a > 0]),c)                                                            Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "r1", value = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L)) : 
replacement has 5 rows, data has 91.                                                                    How to resolve this ?

Comment: @63549  If you need to create that as a column, try `la1$r1 <- NA; i1 <- la1$a >0; la1$r1[i1] <- sapply(gregexpr("transid", la1$dvr[i1])`

Comment: I am getting this error.                                                                                                                  la1$r1[i1] <- sapply(gregexpr("transid",la1$dvr[i1]))
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

Comment: @63549 I forgot the `c`  Please check my code in the post i.e. `la1$r1[i1] <- sapply(gregexpr("transid", la1$dvr[i1]), c)`